# What is RF() here? Is it absolutely necessary here?

Tags: c++

```
class RF
{
    public:
        bitset<32> ReadData1, ReadData2; 
        RF()
        { 
          Registers.resize(32);  
          Registers[0] = bitset<32> (0);  
        }

        void ReadWrite(bitset<5> RdReg1, bitset<5> RdReg2, bitset<5> WrtReg, bitset<32> WrtData, bitset<1> WrtEnable)
        {   
            // implement the funciton by you.                
         }

    void OutputRF() // write RF results to file
             {
               ofstream rfout;
                  rfout.open("RFresult.txt",std::ios_base::app);
                  if (rfout.is_open())
                  {
                    rfout<<"A state of RF:"<<endl;
                  for (int j = 0; j<32; j++)
                      {        
                        rfout << Registers[j]<<endl;
                      }

                  }
                  else cout<<"Unable to open file";
                  rfout.close();

               }     
    private:
            vector<bitset<32> >Registers;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

`RF()` is the constructor, but since all it does is resize `Registers` to 32, you can remove it if you specify that initialization on the member directly, like this:

```
vector<bitset<32> > Registers = vector<bitset<32> >(32);
```

Then `Registers` will be constructed with size 32x32 bits by default, and all the bits will be zero as well, so you can remove the entire `RF()` function.

Note: At first I thought you could use `vector<bitset<32> > Registers{32}` but due to vagaries of C++ syntax that does the wrong thing.  Thanks to Fureeish for that.

Comment: Are you sure that, due to uniform initialisation's interaction with `std::initializer_list` constructors, `{32}` does not initialise `Registers` with a **single** element constructed with said `32`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that, yes, for your current program, it is necessary.

The RF() function in this case is the function called when we initialize the RF object, eg.

`RF new_RF;`

Would run the RF() function and set things up. For this reason, it is called a 'constructor', because it helps you 'construct' your class.

In your case, the constructor is necessary for your program because it sets up your Registers variable, so that the code below from your `OutputRF()` function can run.

```
for (int j = 0; j<32; j++)
{        
    rfout << Registers[j]<<endl;
}
```

It's also useful because we can use it to set up many things, for example, if our RF() constructor looked like this:

```
RF(int a)
{ 
   Registers.resize(a);  
   Registers[0] = bitset<a> (0);  
}
```

It would instead resize the RF Registers to int a. You can look [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/) for a more in-depth tutorial about constructors.

Hope that helps!